# OS Loki notification bubbles

Tags: release-loki, notifications

Since a while the notification bubbles over the application icon in the dock do not disappear anymore. It started with the AppCenter a few weeks ago. Usually, when there are new updates, there was a notification and the bubble above the icon, but after updating the bubble disappeared. Now the bubble stays, even after updating everything. Since a few days I have the same problem with Thunderbird, the bubble stays even after reading all my new emails. After restarting the bubble disappears, but that's not really a long term solution.

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

[image: notification bubbles]
[image: everything up to date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reported bug with the AppCenter.

Check Github Issue [#390](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/390) to read more about it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the same issue has been registered with Thunderbird?

Comment: I'm not a Thunderbird user, sorry. But afaik, no. You can check open bugs for Thunderbird at BugZilla, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/describecomponents.cgi?product=Thunderbird

Answer (score 0):

Try keep the app on Dock and remove after. Work for me. :)

Comment: That works, but it's not an ideal solution. When there's a new notification the problem occurs again.